# Can't call a controller function with argument in ng-repeat - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to execute this [example](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts) in Angular official website. However, I don't know why in this part of the code the first function doesn't work while the second one "pay()" works very well:

```
     <div>
      <b>Total:</b>
      <span ng-repeat="c in invoice.currencies">
         {{ invoice.total(c) | currency:c}}
      </span>
      <button class="btn" ng-click="invoice.pay()">Pay</button>
     </div>
```

Here is my complete code:

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example - example-guide-concepts-3-production</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="invoice3.js"></script>
<script src="finance3.js"></script>
</head>
<body >
<div ng-app="invoice3" ng-controller="InvoiceController as invoice">
<b>Invoice:</b>
<div>
Quantity: <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="invoice.qty" required >
</div>
<div>
Costs: <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="invoice.cost" required >
<select ng-model="invoice.inCurr">
  <option ng-repeat="c in invoice.currencies">{{c}}</option>
</select>
</div>
<div>
<b>Total:</b>
<span ng-repeat="c in invoice.currencies">
  {{ invoice.total(c) | currency:c}}
</span>
<button class="btn" ng-click="invoice.pay()">Pay</button>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

invoice3.js:

```
(function(angular) {
'use strict';
 angular.module('invoice3', ['finance3'])
 .controller('InvoiceController', ['currencyConverter',      function(currencyConverter) {
  this.qty = 1;
  this.cost = 2;
  this.inCurr = 'EUR';
  this.currencies = currencyConverter.currencies;

  this.total = function total(outCurr) {
  return currencyConverter.convert(this.qty * this.cost, this.inCurr, outCurr);
  };
  this.pay = function pay() {
  window.alert("Thanks!");
  };
  }]);
  })(window.angular);
```

finance3.js:

```
  (function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('finance3', [])
  .factory('currencyConverter', ['$http', function($http) {
  var YAHOO_FINANCE_URL_PATTERN =
      '//query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from '+
      'yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in ("PAIRS")&format=json&'+
      'env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
  var currencies = ['USD', 'EUR', 'CNY'];
  var usdToForeignRates = {};

  var convert = function (amount, inCurr, outCurr) {
  return amount * usdToForeignRates[outCurr] / usdToForeignRates[inCurr];
  };

  var refresh = function() {
  var url = YAHOO_FINANCE_URL_PATTERN.
             replace('PAIRS', 'USD' + currencies.join('","USD'));
  return $http.jsonp(url).success(function(data) {
    var newUsdToForeignRates = {};
    angular.forEach(data.query.results.rate, function(rate) {
      var currency = rate.id.substring(3,6);
      newUsdToForeignRates[currency] = window.parseFloat(rate.Rate);
    });
    usdToForeignRates = newUsdToForeignRates;
  });
  };

  refresh();

  return {
  currencies: currencies,
  convert: convert,
  refresh: refresh
  };
  }]);
  })(window.angular);
```

Here is a [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/YgoTRUG8qKL247ynz5PI?p=preview) that works in Plunker, but not on my PC !!
Here is the result on my PC:

[image: result]

Thank you in advance !

Comment: It's not really possible for us to troubleshoot why your PC is acting differently than the Plunker, unless you can show where the code itself is different.  Even copying your code into a blank project and running it locally seems to work; however since this is a JSONP function with a callback, you both need to ensure that you are running the code from a server and not just a `file://` url, and you have to ensure that your firewall isn't blocking anything.

Comment: Yes I am not running my code from a server, I am just using a file://... That's why I think ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I have made a demo with your code, it works.

```
<div>
  <b>Total:</b>
  <span ng-repeat="c in invoice.currencies">
     {{ invoice.total(c) | currency:c}}
  </span>
  <button class="btn" ng-click="invoice.pay()">Pay</button>
 </div>
```

You can check here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Uw5DlVpdTJYFPJ0I7jjB?p=preview

Comment: Yes, there is already a demo link in the web page for my example. The problem is that I don't know why in my PC it doesn't work correctly while in Plunker it works fine? I checked firefox and Safari, in both it doesn't work for me!